# Loading images from database php codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Im trying to load images from the database, i can get the full string and no display on the image and when i use the full array I get a array message.

here is the model :

```
public function get_webstore($webstore_id = '') {
        /* get video */
        if (empty($webstore_id)) {
            $webstores = $this->get('webstore');
        } else {
            $webstores = $this->get('webstore', $webstore_id);
        }

        $webstore_array = array();
        foreach ($webstores as $webstore) {


            $singleWebstorePair = array();
            if (!empty($webstore['images'])) {
                $allWebstores = unserialize($webstore['images']);
                foreach ($allWebstores as $allWestores) {
                    $singleWebstorePair[] = str_replace("./", "", base_url($allWebstores));
                }
            }
            $webstore_array[] = array(
                'id' => $webstore['id'],
                'title' => $webstore['title'],
                'content' => $webstore['content'],
                'images' => $singleWebstorePair,
                'created' => $webstore['created']
            );
        }
        return $webstore_array;
    }
```

and here is the front end code

```
<div class="col-md-12" style="height: 225px;">
                <div class="col-md-4 text-center thumbnail123">
                    <img class="thumbnail" width="225px" src="<?php echo $webstore['images']?>.jpg"/>
                    <h3><?php echo $webstore['title']; ?></h3> 
                    <p>Date Added: <?php echo date('d-m-y', strtotime($webstore['created'])) ?></p>
                     <hr>

                    <hr>
                </div>
```

here is the controller if needed:

```
   public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model("post");
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->helper("url");


    }
    public function index() {

    $this->data['posts'] = $this->post->get_webstore($limit=null, $offset=null); // calling Post model method getPosts()
    $this->data['page_title'] = 'Store';
    $this->layout("pages/webstore", $this->data);
```

and the error:

```
Severity: Notice

Message: Array to string conversion

Filename: pages/webstore.php

Line Number: 45
```

thanks guys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you populate your array, you set `'images' => $singleWebstorePair,˙` which is an array.

In your template, your are echoing this:

`<img class="thumbnail" width="225px" src="<?php echo $webstore['images']?>.jpg"/>`

But here `$webstore['images']` is an array. So if `$webstore['images']` holds multiple image source, then loop through it:

```
<?php foreach($webstore['images'] as $image) : ?>
   <img class="thumbnail" width="225px" src="<?php echo $image ?>.jpg"/>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```